# Twilio: LookupsClient functionality not available in SDK 4.x

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to resolve the following use case and the issue at hand:

## Use case:

For a given number, we need to determine whether the phone number is landline or mobile.

## Environment Setup:

Currently, we've Twilio Nuget v4.7.2 installed and it's showing assembly version '3.4.1.0'

## Question:

Per the LookupsClient documentation link (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups), the following line 'should' work with 4.x SDK. However, appropriate namespace can't be found for:

```
var lookupsClient = new LookupsClient(accountSid, authToken);
```

Thoughts?

[Screenshot Showing issue and Nuget Package Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipnn0.png)

ps: thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: Can you share the rest of the code around that at all? Do you have `using Twilio.Lookups;` at the top of your file?

Comment: @philnash yes, I do have it the 'using Twilio.Lookups'.  Also, I have added a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Hmm, are you sure it's version 4.7.2? That version should have `Twilio.Lookups`. Version 5, however, requires different includes. Check the difference with the version switcher at the top right of the code here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups

Comment: @philnash Yes, 4.7.2 is the installed version.  Also, I have updated the screenshot to include both the error and showing Nuget packaged installed.  I decompiled the Twilio.dll and didn't see a mention of Lookups either.  So either my environment is missing something or perhaps 4.7.2 does not have Lookups functionality altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I am reliably informed that you are correct here and the Twilio Nuget package 4.7.2 does not include the Lookups package.

You have two options now.

Ideally, you should update to [Twilio v5.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio). This has been newly released, contains the Lookups package and will be supported going forwards.

If you cannot update to v5 then you need to install the [Lookups package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.Lookups/) alongside Twilio v4.7.2. Then you can include it and use as expected.

Let me know if that helps at all.